# ImportError: cannot import name 'RasaNLUConfig' from 'rasa_nlu.config' in Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, nlp, rasa, nlu

I'm trying to make a NLU model. When I run

```
from rasa_nlu.config import RasaNLUConfig
```

I get an error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c2bca1b53b6f> in <module>
----> 1 from rasa_nlu.config import RasaNLUConfig
      2 from rasa_nlu.model import Trainer

ImportError: cannot import name 'RasaNLUConfig' from 'rasa_nlu.config' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rasa_nlu/config.py)
```

I thought, "Meh,not a big issue, Colaboratory just hasn't got Rasa installed by default, I'll just install it".
So when I installed it with `!pip install rasa_nlu`, it did everything, and then it told me to restart the runtime and gave me a button to do that. I did that, then I ran `from rasa_nlu.config import RasaNLUConfig` and I still get the same error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'RasaNLUConfig' from 'rasa_nlu.config'
```

I am not familiar with `!apt` so I don't know how I'm supposed to install Rasa with that. Will the problem be solved with that? Or is it something else?

Comment: If you restart your runtime then I guess the module is  not there anymore. Try importing right after install.

Comment: It still doesn't work...

Comment: Does rasa_nlu appear in pip list?

Comment: Yes, in fact, there's a whole bunch of rasa modules when I run `!pip list`:
`
rasa                          2.8.10
rasa-core                     0.9.0a2
rasa-nlu                      0.12.3
rasa-sdk `

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was using a newer version of `rasa_nlu` (0.15.1). The tutorial I was following used 0.11.3. In 0.11.3, `RasaNLUConfig` was located at `from rasa_nlu.config`. But in 0.15.1, it was someplace else.

So... that's solved!